# load existing database to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb database file, which is a dump of some production data. I need to populate my local database with this data. How could I do that? Maybe some monogoimport features exist for that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [mongorestore utility](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/#usage):

```
mongorestore --host localhost
             --port 27017 
             --username user 
             --password pass /backup/dump
```

There is one more tool [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/), but it produces a json or csv.

Comment: I think I should use mongorestore.exe and type command in it, right? If so I have a problem that window of mongorestore utility getting closed right after the opening.

Comment: run that utility from command line or terminal if you are on linux.